# is this inequality incorrect?

Tags: statistics, inequality

Reading my class notes i am not sure if i forgot algebra or if there is mistake in the course notes.

$$ \left[ { \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \mu_0)^2 \over \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})^2 }  \right]^{-n/2} \le c_1  \leftrightarrow \left[ { \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})^2 \over \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \mu_0)^2 }  \right] \ge {1 \over c_1^{2/n}}  $$

$C_1 \in (0, 1)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That inequality is incorrect: the fraction in the left-hand side of the final inequality should be in the same order as the one in the original inequality (no need to flip). This is because if $$\left(\color{teal}{\frac{A}{B}}\right)^{-n/2}\le c_1,$$ where $A,B,c_1>0$, then we can first *invert both sides* to get

$$\left(\frac{A}{B}\right)^{n/2} \color{blue}{\ge} \frac{1}{c_1}.$$

(This is because the inverse of $x^{-a}$ is $x^a$, and inverting both sides of an inequality means we have to flip the inequality sign, assuming both sides of the inequality are the same sign.)

Now we can raise both sides to the power $2/n$ to get

$$\color{teal}{\frac{A}{B}}\ge \frac{1}{c_1^{2/n}}.$$

So the final fraction (in $\color{teal}{\text{teal colour}}$) is the same as the original one, rather than flipped.

Comment: OK, I'll change it.